# asp.net mvc - creating complex view based on stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I'm tinkering with a ASP.NET MVC 4 template, and I need guidance on how to design a complex view layout.

I already created a model that is getting data returned by a stored procedure in a SQL Server DB. A view is getting data from the model in an `IEnumerable<>` object. If you were to view the raw output of the stored procedure it would look something like this:

```
**Name**        **Objects**
John            Orange
John            Banana
John            Apple
```

I used a view template to create a simple table based on logic below, but as expected, it is rendered exactly like it is stored in the `IEnumerable<>` object. The name appears on each row of output in the table, like above.

```
@model IEnumerable<projectname.Models.ObjectsModel>
<table class="table">
...
...
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Objects)
        </td>
...
```

Instead, I want to create a view layout that is not in table form, that would display the Name as a heading, the objects as a bulleted list, and other attributes elsewhere, **with no redundant data**. My problem is that if I display the items in the `IEnumerable<>` using `@foreach (var item in Model)` I end up getting three duplicate entries, since the values in the `Name` field are not unique.

**What is the 'best practice' way to do this?** Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Change the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags in your code above to `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, more or less?

Comment: Instead of using `@Html.DisplayFor` use `@item.<property>` in some HTML structure you want: `<h1>@item.Name</h1><ul><li>@item.Objects</li></ul>`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The main thing i'm trying to figure out is how to display this data without having the `@foreach (var item in Model)` loop generate duplicate entries for each row in the SP output.

Comment: Do you mean you want to group the result by name? If so I guess you can do that with LINQ either in the view or before.

Comment: It would probably help if you included your desired output HTML markup here.  "other attributes elsewhere" what does that mean exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your controller looks like, or even your view model, but maybe i can point you in the right direction.

`foreach` is just that a loop of objects and should be used for just that, i have seen many people manipulate `foreach` loops with little or no success, You should be using a `@for` loop. besides The for-loop is approximately 2 times faster than the foreach-loop as it only has to call `get_Item` for every element in the list.

there are a few ways to acomplis what you want, one way would be what @colinD stated above by using LINQ in the controler or viewmodel to pass the proper data. the other way would be somthing similar to the following.

```
var models = ObjectsModel();
    var grouped = models.GroupBy(s => s.ObjectsModel.Name)
    .Select(x => x.Select(y => y))
    .ToList();
    return View(grouped);

    @for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
     <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i].First().ObjectsModel.Name)</h2>
    <ul>
        for(int j = 0; j < Model[i].Count; j++)
        {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model[i][j].Object)</li>
        }
    </ul>
    }
```

I haven't tested the code but I hope this helps you get the right solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> The main thing i'm trying to figure out is how to display this data
>   without having the @foreach (var item in Model) loop generate
>   duplicate entries for each row in the SP output.

Usually processing data is done in `action`, like groupping data, and then make some loop to display. As you want to avoid `@foreach` I thought using linq. This is just an idea but keep in mind you should separate concerns in MVC. I hope this helps ;)

```
IEnumerable<ObjectsModel> model = new List<ObjectsModel>()
{
    new ObjectsModel(){ Name = "John", Objects = "Orange" },
    new ObjectsModel(){ Name = "John", Objects = "Banana" },
    new ObjectsModel(){ Name = "John", Objects = "Apple" }
};
var htmlModel = model
    .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
    .Select(a => new
    {
        Name = a.Key,
        GroupObjects = string.Join("", a.Select(b => $"<li>{b.Objects}</li>"))
    })
    .Select(a => $"<h1>{a.Name}</h1><ul>{a.GroupObjects}</ul>")
    .ToList();
var result = string.Join("", htmlModel); // <h1>John</h1><ul><li>Orange</li><li>Banana</li><li>Apple</li></ul>
```

Final result:

```
<h1>John</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```